# How to redirect a subdomain to main domain - NGINX Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, nginx

I really don't know anything about this, so here I go.
I need to redirect play.example.net to [www.example.net](http://www.example.net) on the browser. the "play" subdomain is used for a game. But [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is my website.

I tried this

> server {
> listen 80;
> server_name play.example.net;
> return 301 https://example.net$request_uri; }

It worked, play.example.net now is redirecting to example.net ... But now my website is down, if you look for example.net now it will timeout.

Any idea?

Comment: Just for clarification: You main domain is just example.com. Both play. and www. are subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/play.example.com` file (or whatever you might have it called on your machine), you'll need to add a `rewrite` that points to `example.com` like so:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name play.example.net;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 permanent;
    ...
}
```

Once this is done, save the file and check that the config is good with: `nginx -t`. So long as no errors are returned, reload nginx:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Hope this gets your site back online